# Issue with Next.js useProviders returning null for authentication providers in Nav component

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I m trying to make a nextjs website and im using provider in that but my provider is showing null al the time i tried to debug it with the help of bard and chatgpt but was helpless.

**This is my Nav.jsx code and in this i have error with provider,the provider is null can someone tell me the reason**

```
"use client";

import Link from "next/link";
import Image from "next/image";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { signIn, signOut, useSession, getProviders } from "next-auth/react";

const Nav = () => {
    const { data: session } = useSession();

    const [providers, setProviders] = useState();
    const [toggleDropdown, setToggleDropdown] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
            const res = await getProviders();
            setProviders(res);
        })();
    }, []);
    
    return (
        <nav className='flex-between w-full mb-16 pt-3'>
            <Link href='/' className='flex gap-2 flex-center'>
                <Image
                    src='/assets/images/logo.svg'
                    alt='logo'
                    width={30}
                    height={30}
                    className='object-contain'
                />
                <p className='logo_text'>Promptopia</p>
            </Link>

            {/* Desktop Navigation */}
            <div className='sm:flex hidden'>
                {session?.user ? (
                    <div className='flex gap-3 md:gap-5'>
                        <Link href='/create-prompt' className='black_btn'>
                            Create Post
                        </Link>

                        <button type='button' onClick={signOut} className='outline_btn'>
                            Sign Out
                        </button>

                        <Link href='/profile'>
                            <Image
                                src={session?.user.image}
                                width={37}
                                height={37}
                                className='rounded-full'
                                alt='profile'
                            />
                        </Link>
                    </div>
                ) : (
                    <>
                        {providers &&
                            Object.values(providers).map((provider) => (
                                <button
                                    type='button'
                                    key={provider.name}
                                    onClick={() => {
                                        signIn(provider.id);
                                    }}
                                    className='black_btn'
                                >
                                    Sign in
                                </button>
                            ))}
                    </>
                )}
            </div>

            {/* Mobile Navigation */}
            <div className='sm:hidden flex relative'>
                {session?.user ? (
                    <div className='flex'>
                        <Image
                            src={session?.user.image}
                            width={37}
                            height={37}
                            className='rounded-full'
                            alt='profile'
                            onClick={() => setToggleDropdown(!toggleDropdown)}
                        />

                        {toggleDropdown && (
                            <div className='dropdown'>
                                <Link
                                    href='/profile'
                                    className='dropdown_link'
                                    onClick={() => setToggleDropdown(false)}
                                >
                                    My Profile
                                </Link>
                                <Link
                                    href='/create-prompt'
                                    className='dropdown_link'
                                    onClick={() => setToggleDropdown(false)}
                                >
                                    Create Prompt
                                </Link>
                                <button
                                    type='button'
                                    onClick={() => {
                                        setToggleDropdown(false);
                                        signOut();
                                    }}
                                    className='mt-5 w-full black_btn'
                                >
                                    Sign Out
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        )}
                    </div>
                ) : (
                    <>
                        {providers &&
                            Object.values(providers).map((provider) => (
                                <button
                                    type='button'
                                    key={provider.name}
                                    onClick={() => {
                                        signIn(provider.id);
                                    }}
                                    className='black_btn'
                                >
                                    Sign in
                                </button>
                            ))}
                    </>
                )}
            </div>
        </nav>
    );
};

export default Nav;
```

Want to know why provider is null and want to get it fixed

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

kindly provide more context where your problem has occured..

based on your information , these may be something to look after :

1. Add nextAuth Providers, at first providers will return null only untill you signin with some specific providers
2. Look for route handler which handles the next auth providers

Try these first and if error still occurs let me know :)

Comment: Is that okay if i share my github link of my project sir ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are from JavascriptMastery, you are probably having a newer version of next-auth installed.

Use these commands to install the right version.

> `npm uninstall next-auth`

then

> `npm i next-auth@4.22.1`